# Prevent reaching database from outside of web application

Tags: java, database, block, document

I am developing document management system as a web based application using java technologies. I have to prevent database access in any way except this app. None of way can not update any table on this system such as directy using a sql query. This kind of sample is SAP.

AS I guess, SAP company has a middle tier structure and there is not any way to manupulate any data. It allows only using SAP gui and transcations mechanish to alter, create or delete andy data.

My app has many user rights to do any thing on the system and I have to guarantee that data can not bu changed on database except this application.
What I want to do is this kind of architecture. Can you give me some idea, how can I achieve this for my application?

Thanks

Comment: Don't give the password of the database user to anyone and trust in your dba's?

Answer (score 0):

You need to program two applications: A client application and a server application. The client application is installed on the users machine and communicates with the server application installed on a server. The server application then communicates with the backend database.

There are many possible ways to do this.

It's your decision how much business logic you want to have on the server and how much you want to have on the client. It can be anything between the server being not much more than a proxy for the database while the client does everything or a very thin client which is just a dumb GUI with the whole logic running on the server (that would be what SAP is doing).

There are also lots of options for communicating between client and server.

Listing all possible options would be too much for a single answer.

Comment: This app is a web based solution and there is no installation on client side. Clients will open browser, login to system. They can not access to db already except app. 

My concern is at the server side especially. For instance, even IT team of the company can not be able to modify at the server side on the db. System admin, manager also have to use this app (login to system as admin or if has rights to do any job).

Comment: @devrim Then what exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I prevent writing to db with any sql query or from 3.part sql editors without using my application?

Comment: @devrim this sounds like a question about how to set permissions for whatever SQL database you are using. Such questions would fit better on dba.stackexchange.com.